# how to add DatePicker to a tablecolumn

Tags: javafx

How can I add a date picker to a tablecolumn.
I tried to do the same method to add textfield or checkbox (tablecolumn.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(tablecolumn)))
But I think that DatePickerTableCell doesn’t exist

Comment: You can check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26237863/1759128), which does the same for `ProgressBar` in a `TableView`

Comment: It works but it's not exactely what I want,

Comment: It works but it's not exactly what I want, because, the DatePicker is shown from the beginning, I want them to be visible just after double click on the column and to keep the old values