# How to add a datepicker to a treetableview column

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to add a datepicker to treetableview column. Please guide me.

Comment: You might want to go through this - [UI controls in TreeTableView](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26237863/1759128)

Answer (score 0):

Use tableCellRenderer. Follow this tutorial : http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-cell-renderer/

TreeTableView and TableView Api's are almost similar.

Comment: I want a datepicker on my column cell so that I can choose the date from calender. Any idea how to get that graphic.