# JavaFX - TableView ProgressBar (Error - setCellValueFactory cannot be applied)

Tags: progress-bar, tableview, javafx-8

Am creating a TableView with ProgressBar using FXML. I am getting a error as below for the line which contains ProgressBarTableCell in the code below. I referred to [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721380/javafx-update-progressbar-in-tableview-from-task) & [Link2](http://www.coderanch.com/t/633811/JavaFX/java/Performing-Task-Service-TableView-ProgressBar) but unable to figure out what mistake I am doing.

**Error:**

```
'setCellValueFactory(javafx.util.Callback<javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<model.TableDisplayData,java.lang.Double>,javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue<java.lang.Double>>)' 

in 'javafx.scene.control.TableColumn' cannot be applied to

'(javafx.util.Callback<javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<model.TableDisplayData,java.lang.Double>,javafx.scene.control.TableCell<model.TableDisplayData,java.lang.Double>>)'
```

**Code:**

```
@FXML
private TableView<TableDisplayData> tvDisplay;
@FXML
private TableColumn<TableDisplayData,String> colCarModel;
@FXML
private TableColumn<TableDisplayData,String> colModelIndicator;
@FXML
private TableColumn<TableDisplayData,Double> colSpeedProgress;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
colCarModel.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableDisplayData, String>("car"));
colModelIndicator.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableDisplayData, String>("indicator"));
colSpeedProgress.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableDisplayData, Double>("progressBar"));
colSpeedProgress.setCellValueFactory(ProgressBarTableCell.<TableDisplayData> forTableColumn());
}
```

**Code for TableDisplayData:**

```
public class TableDisplayData{
private String car;
private String indicator;
private DoubleProperty progressBar = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

public TableDisplayData(String car, String indicator, double progressBar) {
    this.car= car;
    this.indicator = indicator;
    setProgressBar(progressBar);
}
getters & setters....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing the `cellFactory` with the `cellValueFactory`. The `cellValueFactory` tells the column *what* data to display. The `cellFactory` tells the column *how* to display the data.

So you need

```
colSpeedProgress.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableDisplayData, Double>("progressBar"));
colSpeedProgress.setCellFactory(ProgressBarTableCell.<TableDisplayData> forTableColumn());
```

(note the second line is changed to `setCellFactory`, not `setCellValueFactory`).